# Flutter WebView: JavaScript execution is not updating the web view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterwebviewplugin

I am running javascript code in the WebView of my Flutter application in order to remove the header of a certain page. I tested the javascript code in a JS console, and it works fine, however it doesn't alter my WebView at all. Here is my code

```
class CoreWebScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const CoreWebScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.url,
  }) : super(key: key);
  final String url;

  @override
  State<CoreWebScreen> createState() => _CoreWebScreenState();
}

class _CoreWebScreenState extends State<CoreWebScreen> {
  WebViewController? _webViewController;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: WebView(
        initialUrl: widget.url,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _webViewController = webViewController;
        },
        onPageFinished: (page) async {
          await _webViewController?.runJavascript(_removeHeader());
          setState(() {});
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  String _removeHeader() {
    return r'''javascript:(function() { document.getElementById('root').getElementsByClassName('f1e663')[0].getElementsByClassName('_060cef')[0].style.display = 'none'; })()''';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
      controller.runJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].style.display='none'");          
            };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).